# USB port not functionning anymore on Samsung Galaxy Tab S3i

Tags: usb

After installing software for an endoscope USB device, my USB port stopped functionning (no more tethering, no battery charging from adapter, tablet icon doesn't appear in Windows explorer). The software worked fine with device connected. Uninstalled it, but still can't use the port. Is there a way to reinitialise the port? When the tablet is off and I plug it into the charger, I can see te circled animation for the battery, but no percentage is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the app you have also tested the USB microscope, right? If yes most likely this broke your USB port physically. Also that the device does not charge correctly when powered off is a strong indicator that you are facing a hardware and not a software problem.

When the USB port does not work correctly this usually means that the soldering points are broken so that electrical power sometimes can pass the USB port, however it is way too less to charge the device (loose connection).

To fix this the device most be opened and the USB port have to be re-soldered, sometimes also the USB port have to be replaced.

Comment: It makes sense. I'll bring it to the Samsung shop for checking.